# Center of mass, center of gravity of a spoon

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I went to a restaurant yesterday and while I was eating dessert, I saw a **standard stainless steel spoon (note the alliteration!**) balancing on a plate. It was balancing on its handle, and I started wondering,

Why is that particular point the center of gravity for the spoon?
Thanks.

Comment: For such small objects the center of mass can be assumed to be the same as the center of gravity, because gravitational acceleration hardly changes within the volume of the spoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that a typical handle of a spoon was more than twice as long as its bowl.  I would also expect the handle tends to be thicker and wider away from the bowl, while the bowl tends to be fairly symmetric front to back.

If these assumptions applied in a particular case where the mass (or weight) of the handle was at least half that of the bowl, then the centre of mass (or gravity) of the whole spoon would have to be somewhere along the handle (or just below it, depending on the design of the spoon) rather somewhere in (or just above) the bowl.

This is because the centre of mass of the bowl is near its centre (less than a quarter of the handle length from where the handle meets the bowl), while the centre of mass of the handle is more than half a handle length from where the handle meets the bowl.  The centre of mass of the spoon is then the weighted average of the centres of mass of the bowl and the handle, where the weights are the respective masses. (My apologies for using *weight* in a mathematical rather than physical sense.)

sihrc has suggested:

Assume a center of gravity: Divide the spoon at that point. Torque analysis: T = FR and T = Ia. The COG of the bowl side is closer to the center and the handle side is further, assuming bowl is shorter than handle. Bowl is also heavier per distance from the pivot than the handle because the bowl is wider than the handle.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain it in terms of moment of inertia or equations? I find it easier to understand physics in terms of math than conceptual

Comment: @Abhishek Mallela: I have added a paragraph which you should be able to turn in equations and inequalities